# Azure Powershell passwordless authentication

Tags: azure, powershell

Looking for some help. Is there a way to use powershell to connect to Azure using a certificate, keyvault, or runas account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create service principal and configure certificate-based authentication. Take a look on [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-7.0.0#create-a-service-principal) for more details on how to set it up step by step.